# Using a scripting language for camel recipientList aggregator

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I'm working on a project using Camel and for various reasons it would be better if we avoided any Java code.  Don't ask...!

At the moment I'm using a recipentList with a small aggregator that just concatenates the messages together, so a few lines.  But I'm trying to find out if it's possible to do without even those lines and move the activity into the route definition.

So far I have

```
<bean id="docGenAggregator" class="local.dev.scatterGather.DocGenAggregator">
....
<recipientList 
        strategyRef="docGenAggregator" 
        strategyMethodName="docGenRequest">
  <header>documentPartsList</header>
</recipientList>
```

which is working ok.  The recipientList in this case is actually a list of xslt:... endpoints each returning xml and I just want the concatenation of all of the returned xml.

My bean is currently

```
package local.dev.scatterGather;

public class DocGenAggregator {

    public String docGenRequest(String existing, String next) {
        return existing + next; 
    }

}
```

Examples of using scripting (don't really care on language, I'm already way up the steep learning curve on this so a little more won't really make a difference!)

Thanks

Comment: You may be able to use groovy and write the groovy code in the xml file as a bean, maybe there is some ways of doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use inline a groovy script to do this. I created an unit test in Apache Camel to demonstrate this.

```
  <!-- inline a groovy script to use for the aggregator -->
  <lang:groovy id="myAggregate">
    <lang:inline-script>
      class MyAggregate {
        String someNameHere(String prev, int next) {
          return prev * next
        }
      }
    </lang:inline-script>
  </lang:groovy>
```

And then from the aggregate you need to tell the method name to use, as the groovy class has some extra methods Camel do not skip by default

```
  <!-- we must declare the name of the method, as the inlined groovy script has additional methods -->
  <aggregate strategyRef="myAggregate"
             strategyMethodName="someNameHere"
             completionSize="2">
```

The complete example is in this commit: https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/1c7a2d749e5f75545aa9899e9b06cdef4cf1d614

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for.  I've not done any groovy before but this was easy to sort out and get working in no time.  Thank you.

Comment: Claus, is groovy working as a scripting language out-of-the-box now? Or do you need to add pom dependencies for the scripting languages you need.

Comment: I've added camel-script (well, it was already there) and camel-groovy to my pom file, more details on http://camel.apache.org/groovy.html